# Curl and cookie

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm using cURL to log in a website, but I don't know how to get/use the cookies I get.

Does anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625111/php-and-curl-cookies

Comment: This Ask Metafilter article contains several helpful examples. http://ask.metafilter.com/18923/How-do-you-handle-authentication-via-cookie-with-CURL

Answer (score 3):

http://ask.metafilter.com/18923/How-do-you-handle-authentication-via-cookie-with-CURL

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, this example will help...

```
#!/bin/bash
COOKIE_FILE="cookie.tmp"
MAIN_URL="http://localhost:8080/monitor"

if [ -e $COOKIE_FILE ] ; then
    rm $COOKIE_FILE
fi

curl -d "j_username=user&j_password=pass" -c $COOKIE_FILE "$MAIN_URL/j_spring_security_check"

DATA=`curl -b $COOKIE_FILE "$MAIN_URL/host/list.json"`

curl --get -b $COOKIE_FILE "$MAIN_URL/host/addHost.json?newHostAddress=192.168.77.197&newHostPort=9990"

rm $COOKIE_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'someKey=' . $_COOKIE['someVal . '; path=/');
```

and you have a cookie in your request.
if u need more then one cookie, look up this function on php.net and find "cookie file" or if u need to save cookies from the response find "cookie jar"