# Sending cookie values in php curl

Tags: php

I haved logined to the site using curl and at that time I am saving the cookies in some file 
'abc.txt'.

Now to proceed further I want to read the cookies that I have saved in 'abc.txt' and send them to other page of same site.

How can I do that in PHP  .. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860030/curl-and-cookie

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP reading a cookie file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410109/php-reading-a-cookie-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option in your cURL resource:

```
$cookie_file = 'abc.txt';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**
>   The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.

If you want cURL to dump cookies to a file after it has completed processing a URL, then you need to set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` option:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
```

> **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR**
>   The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to `curl_close`.

Comment: I am doing exactly like this .. but how can I read the cookies I have stored in abc.txt

Comment: @new_developer:  What do you mean by 'read'?  Do you want a human readable list of cookies printed, or do you want cURL to use them again next time it does an operation, like what I have above?

Comment: @new_developer:  I have marked the question as a duplicate as one that I believe contains the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I looked at it . It was exactly what I want .. Thanks