# cURL won't trigger setcookie

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL script that is sending login info to a script.

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
//open connection
```

The script has a setcookie function.

```
setcookie("cookie_email",$email,time()+(3600*24*$i),"/");
setcookie("cookie_password",$password,time()+(3600*24*$i),"/");
```

When I login to the form using the form everything works as expected. For some reason when you run the cURL it's skipping the setcookies function.

I've been all over the net and I can't find a solution.  I'm not sure why it's failing to set the cookies.

Any step in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Phil

UPDATE! - Getting Closer

Okay I have made some changes that grab cookies and put them into a cookie file.  Two Issues I set.
1.  The cookied password in the file reads: deleted
2. The cookies aren't being set in the browser.

How do I get the md5($password) into the file and how does:
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt'); 
set the cookies in the browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP and cURL cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625111/php-and-curl-cookies)

Comment: I'm using a facebook registration form that points to a submit.php script on my server.  The script adds the user to the database and then retrieves the username and password it just generated and sends them to the login script.  The login script sets the cookies.

Another thread mentions the user needs to hit the site before the browser will allow a cookie to be set.  Doesn't them hitting my submit script accomplish this?  OR Could I set a Cookie Variable with the goods and them process the script?

Comment: `UserBrowser->YourScript` and `YourScript->ServerForm` are distinct HTTP connections then. Cookies won't jump over. Passing them on, probably won't help. (Too few details.)

Answer (score 2):

You must set the CURL_COOKIEJAR and CURL_COOKIEFILE options for curl to set where cookies should be stored and loaded from respectively.

EDIT: Your example rewritten:

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

This assumes you have created a directory 'cookies/' and will save the cookies in a file called 'cookies.txt' (as long as your webserver can write to that directory, it will create the file itself)

Subsequent requests will then use any cookies stored in cookies.txt when sending their request (assuming you set the cookiefile for that request as well)

Comment: Thanks Majic!  I don't know how to do that.  I didn't understand it on php.net.  Do I create the cookie file and put it on the server?  Do you have an example I could look at?

Comment: I have edited my response with an updated version of your code. The CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR is where the cookie response will be saved. The CURL_COOKIEFILE is where to load cookies from for a request. Initially this will be empty, but for subsequent requests it will contain the previously saved cookies.

Comment: Since my first page in my curl goes to a submit script with a header() to the login script.  Do I need two curl functions then?  I have to turn on:
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
In order for it to process all the way through.  

I added the lines you wrote and It's processing through and landing at my target page but it's still not logged in.

Comment: Once you are successfully logged in, you should make a subsequent request with curl to read data from the logged in page, consider the first request the login and the subsequent requests as the "logged in" requests. You can re-initialize your curl handle, request the URL you want to read as as a logged in user and be sure to specify the same CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE in the request so it sends the previously stored cookies.

Comment: I'm not getting to the successfully logged in part.  It's redirecting me to the page but it's not setting any cookies.. I copied the curl after again after the first curl and ran it again and it's not putting anything into the cookie.txt file.  So if I understand this.. Curl cookie is suppose to grab any cookies it comes accross and store them in the cookie.txt file?

Comment: Correct, during the inital request any response cookies that are set as a result of the login are stored into the 'cookies.txt' file -- this is due to the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR option, it specifies where to store them. When another request is sent and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE is set to the same file as specified in the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, it loads those cookies back out of the file and sends them along with the request. If nothing is ever being stored in the file, make sure you have write permission where you are attempting to write and that the  page is setting cookies correctly.

Comment: I've got the cookie files working.  However it's not pulling the cookie from the login script. Will curl pull data after a header()? This is an auto register auto login script.  So the curl goes to the signup script first and then I have it set to redirect to the login script where it runs into the cookies.  Should I set this up to run 3 times.  Signup, Get Cookies, Then Login?  Thanks again for your effort... I'm making progress.  ~Phil