# User information getting lost on scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping

Right now, I am logged into a website which shows my username in the header, indicating that I am logged-in.

Now, when I try to scrape that web-page and display the result on my m/c, the page header shows "Sign-in" indicating that I need to login.

I think I am missing some cookie info in my scraping that I need to consider.

Is there any way I can also read the cookies.

CURL code:

```
function getString( $url ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt' );
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: have you considered using CURL ???

Comment: I have used it, but still the same result.

Comment: What is *"my m/c"*? Also *simplehtmldom* is not even good for parsing html, but it's also not good for scraping. Setup your HTTP requests with PHP (see HTTP context options) or use curl instead and then request the HTML data your own and pass that over to the HTML parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP and cURL cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625111/php-and-curl-cookies) - that question describes the exact scenario you have.

Comment: @hakra - ok, will try without simplehtmldom. thanks

Comment: The HTML parser is not your problem here. Your issue is with the HTTP requests and responses. So even I won't stop you from dropping that html library (you can just take `DomDocument` from PHP), that alone would not solve your problem.

Comment: @Baba - the code is put in the question.

Comment: @Pushpesh You are logged _in your browser_. How do you arrange for your browser cookies to end up in the `cookie.txt` file you provide to Curl for cookie storage?

Comment: @ Pushpesh you need to set the full cookie path

Comment: @Pushpesh has this been resolved

Comment: @Baba - i am working on it based on the code you gave. I'll post an update once i get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working becasue of the full path Cookie Path and make sure the `cookie.txt` is writable

Try

```
var_dump(getString("http://google.com"));

    function getString($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $cookie =  __DIR__ . '/cookie.txt' ;
    touch($cookie);

    if(!is_writable($cookie))
    {
        die("Can't write to cookie");
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

cookie.txt output

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.google.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1411737249  PREF    ID=ff7979720d6a1237:FF=0:TM=1348665249:LM=1348665249:S=bRYSIBSW9Cd7PKOr
#HttpOnly_.google.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1364476449  NID 64=tcm3RUM8R_1ch9eD6tuFi4lObBjSNdxqwMHbpchYCQoUpghIjZbiNw8AdAm0buTAVF0SqUsZsYEs7PAWhJdhutO11EQ9y8iXwuQ9dsPmdWlt86BAa7hxRqQcjSoX9Bep
.google.com.ng  TRUE    /   FALSE   1411737252  PREF    ID=9428863ec2e741f5:FF=0:TM=1348665252:LM=1348665252:S=s7wtyWMM9OnRYoE4
#HttpOnly_.google.com.ng    TRUE    /   FALSE   1364476452  NID 64=Gyszb-4_10nzvSU6kGzBj5UQRTnB7purbAH0reBytKi_pn9m3R-0BXGBEjrkmMBmOYfFpfIQOYLaCgi5LfKOIcnPCrTpTpV9LVld-Xf9pq7U7W5QaZ63a_yHIG9Vmcir
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate content. Instead help to point to existing resources, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Well have fun with the debugging session then ;).

Comment: @hakra .. it would be nice to see how it ends